telegraf [[outputs.prometheus_client]] only scrapes localhost metrics
there is only one instance of telegraf is running which is /etc/telegraf
I added one more output source to redirect metrics to prometheus client via output plugin in /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf
[[outputs.prometheus_client]]
    listen = ":9110"
    path = "/metrics"

the config also contains output client for influxdb
telegraf instance was restarted. /etc/telegraf/telegraf.d/ contains *.conf for multiple hosts that should be scraped. When I check prometheus client output via curl://http:localhost:9110/metrics I only see metrics from localhost but not from all host as I expect
